# Which local database would best be suited for a React + Firestore based app?

Tags: reactjs, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a ReactJS app. I'm currently using Firestore as an online DB.

The thing is, I want the app to be usable offline + store user-specific data locally as well.

Which database system would be best suited for minimal communication between Firebase and the local system?

Comment: If you're using Cloud Firestore, then offline persistence is built-in. For web you just have to enable it, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline. If that doesn't suit your needs, technology recommendations are unfortunately off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Will go through that.